# I'm very tired because I travelled for several hours this morning

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

According to another thread, sentences 1, 3, and 4 are correct. But sentence 2 doesn't sound idiomatic. Would you please explain the reason?

In the afternoon, I said,

1. I'm very tired because I **was travelling** for several hours this morning.
2. I'm very tired because I **travelled** for several hours this morning.

In the late evening, I said,

3. I'm wide awake because I **was sleeping** for several hours this afternoon.
4. I'm wide awake because I **slept** for several hours this afternoon.

My guess is as follows:

To make one tired is not very easy, so we must highlight the length of the activity. Past continuous can make this effect, whereas past simple can't.

On the contrary, to make one wide awake is not very hard. Even a nap in the earlier period can make you wide awake. Even a cup of coffee can make you wide awake (I'm wide awake because I drank a cup of coffee this afternoon). So we don't need to highlight the length of sleeping.

Comment: The thing is 'idiomatic' in this context often means there's no logical reason why one thing sounds better than another.  This can often be regional.  Take, for example, the phase 'fine by me' which is equivalent to 'fine with me'.  In some regions, it sounds normal, but for a lot of people it sounds odd, even wrong, to use 'by' instead of 'with' in that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I dispute your premise. (2) sounds perfectly fine to me, and I am a native speaker. Consider the following, which has exactly the same grammatical form:

I'm very tired because I travelled all day yesterday!

I agree with Colin that (3) is non-idiomatic, but not with the reason. It is perfectly fine to say:

He was sleeping for several hours this afternoon.

But not:

I'm wide awake because I was sleeping for several hours this afternoon.

This is because of "because", which here implies that the reason for you being wide awake is the *continuous process* of sleeping that went on this afternoon. No, you are wide awake because of the *completion* of your afternoon nap, so "was sleeping" and "had been sleeping" are inappropriate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133076/discussion-on-answer-by-user21820-im-very-tired-because-i-travelled-for-several).

Answer (score 3):

I don't find anything wrong with 2.

The one which seemed odd to me was 3, but I think this is because I don't have *is/are/was/were sleeping* in my vocabulary, except in a habitual sense. I always say *asleep* rather than *sleeping*.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, sentences 1, 2 and 4 sound idiomatic to me, but 3 does not.  I would probably say, “because I was asleep,” not “*because I was sleeping.”  I honestly am not sure why.  It seems to be exactly parallel to other sentences that sound perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all would sound correct, but 2 would make me think for an extra second before understanding it. I think it is because travelling is often measured in distance, rather than time, so if someone says "This morning I travelled..." my brain would be expecting a distance to come next, not a time, while "was travelling for..." implies a time.

Whereas sleep can only really be measured in terms of time, or perhaps quality, so the brain would not necessarily expect something else.

Comment: Can you provide any sources to back up your assertion that we do not say we have travelled for a period of time? It sounds perfectly natural to me.

Comment: @mdewey The problem is not "have travelled  for a period of time" but" I'm tired because I've travelled for several hours". Someone said it's not idiomatic and "because I've been travelling for several hours" should be used.